# AppEngine: forwarding request to static-content

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, http-headers

In order to optimize caching, I added timestamps to the src values of images, etc, e.g. `<img src="/static/img/foo.1456871418309.png"/>.`

Then I created a servlet filter which removes the timestamps again, and then forwards the request to the resource. `request.getRequestDispatcher (urlWithoutTimestamp).forward(request, response)`.

And in `appengine-web.xml` I specified to cache files a year.

```
<static-files>
    <include path="/static/**" expiration="365d" />
</static-files>
```

This way, I thought, the user would always get the latest version and can cache it until a newer version exists, without having to test it via HTTP.

On localhost (Run As Web Application) this works fine, the HTTP response has the expected caching headers:

```
Cache-Control:"public, max-age=31536000"
Expires:"Wed, 01 Mar 2017 22:54:32 GMT"
```

However when I deploy the whole thing on the app engine server the response has this caching header (and no “Expires”):

```
Cache-Control:"private"
```

Instead of forwarding the request, I also tried calling the FilterChain on a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to modify the getRequestURI, getRequestURL, getServletPath. This lead to the same poor result.

How do I get this right?

**Update:**

On second thought, I guess forwarding to static-content may not be possible, because forwarding is always done server locally and the static-content may well be served on another machine.

But at least I was able to solve my HTTP header problem with my filter:

1. Instead of forwarding the request, I use a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` (see above) to remove the timestamp from the request.
2. Then I call chain.doFilter on the modified request.
3. Last I set the caching headers on the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of changing filename and using a filter you can reference actual static file with timestamp added as request parameter.

Instead of:

```
<img src="/static/img/foo.1456871418309.png"/>
```

use following schema:

```
<img src="/static/img/foo.png?r=1456871418309"/>
```

For static file such parameters are ignored. But for browser it will be a new URL each time, therefore it will be requested from the server.

Comment: This sounds like a very good idea! I will try it as soon as possible :) 

(Just for better understanding: It’s not the current timestamp, but one I set to a final static variable at the first request since server start – best would be a timestamp at compile time or deployment time, but not sure how to do this yet.)

Comment: that value will work too. you don't need it to be uniq between requests i guess, just between different versions of the app

Answer (score 1):

In production, you will not be able to intercept static file traffic. Google App Engine takes care of static files for you, basically providing a sort of CDN.

I quote the note on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Filters

> Filters are not invoked on static assets, even if the path matches a
>   filter-mapping pattern. Static files are served directly to the
>   browser.

Comment: From my experience, this is not the whole truth. Looks like every resource exists both as dynamic and static resource -- and with applying a filter, the dynamic resource is chosen. I guess this somehow explains my problem: `<static-files>` don’t apply to my filtered resource

Comment: Well, by default, all files in the WAR are treated as both static files and resource files, except for JSP files. (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files). That said, statically define files within the `appengine-web.xml` will be directly served by Google and not hit your app. being also resources mean that you can also access them via `java.io.File` or `javax.servlet.ServletContext.getResource/getResourceAsStream`. Without more info, I am not sure why `<static-file>` directive is not taken effect in Production.

Comment: It seems to me that `<static-file>` works for actually existing files, e.g. `foo.png` but go to the app engine (and its filters), if they do not exist (e.g. foo.1456871418309.png). Is that correct? However once at the App Engine there seems to be no way back to the Machine which serves the static files …

Comment: Correct, thats the case. If the file does not exist, the requests cascades to your application. Indeed there is no way to redirect to the static serving file.